# RewriteCond makes includes 404

Tags: html, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having issues to change an address from:

```
http://localhost/project/maps/pages/route.php?id=6680342be54df196c6cceba6624a10374dd6c51c1484853317
```

to

```
http://localhost/project/route/6680342be54df196c6cceba6624a10374dd6c51c1484853317
```

I managed to do it via htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^routes/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) maps/pages/route.php?id=$1
```

But now im having 404 on all my includes inside route.php e.g:

```
<link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

My folders are like this:

```
www
->project
 ->index.php
 ->maps
  ->vendor
   ->bootstrap
    ->css
     ->bootstrap.min.css
  ->pages
   ->route.php
```

I dont want to change anything inside `maps` folder because that is an app that is developed by someone else, but I dont want my website to look like:

`http://localhost/project/maps/pages/route.php`

instead I want something that, once uploaded to my server would look like

`http://website.com/route/6680342be54df196c6cceba6624a10374dd6c51c1484853317`

without the need of dumping the files on the main folder. In other words, how can I make the folder `maps`, to work totally separated but with a different address?

Thanks.

Comment: Why does your css link not have `maps/` in it?

Comment: because i am calling it from 'route.php' which is inside pages' folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a redirect rule to fix the `/vendor/` path:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maps/ [NC]
RewriteRule (?:^|/)((?:vendor|data|dist|js|mapicon|includes)/.+)$ maps/$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^routes/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ maps/pages/route.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I just tried that and I'm still having 38 404 errors.. any other workaround?

Comment: This is one of the errors I get on the browser `GET 404 http://myproject.com/vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js` and from the logs `"GET /vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404`

Comment: The same happens with `bootstrap.min.css` they are both inside `vendor` folder. I just checked, and php includes are working fine. `include_once('../includes/header.php');` did include the header.php but then it cant find `<link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` (that line is inside header.php). And my .htaccess has exactly the same as you posted

Comment: that worked for vendors folder! I suppose all I have to do is to replicate those two lines for each of my folders inside `maps` right?

Comment: data, dist, js, less, mapicon, vendor, includes, pages those are all